# Multiple cross apply in SQL for a row with json

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, open-json

I have a row:

```
id, shipping_data, line_data
0, '[{"name": "Greg", "Address": "test address"}]', '[{"products": "apple", "cost": "0.50"'}'
```

and I want to expand the row to display all data in one row.

I tried using multiple cross applies:

```
SELECT id, A.*, B.*
FROM table t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.[shipping_data]) 
    WITH (
          name nvarchar(max),
          Address nvarchar(max)
         ) A;
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.[line_data])
    WITH (
          products nvarchar(max),
          cost nvarchar(max)
         ) B;
```

Comment: What is the issue ? Post the result what you are getting and Expected result

Comment: Drop the `;` after your `A` alias ..... the `;` is a statement **terminator** and thus your statements ends there - the second `CROSS JOIN` is not part of your `SELECT` statement anymore....

Comment: Also the `line_data` isn't a valid JSON value. Perhaps that's a transcription error when posting the question?

Comment: I also suggest you rethink those data types. For example `cost should be `decimal(9,2)`  and the text columns should not be `max`